# Can't run middleman server. What's wrong?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, middleman

I'm using Windows, I have Ruby21 (`C:\Ruby21`) and RubyDevKit (`C:\RubyDevKit`) installed.

I want to build a site with Middleman, and I found these articles by [Ben Frain](https://benfrain.com/understanding-middleman-the-static-site-generator-for-faster-prototyping/), [Brett Klamer](http://brettklamer.com/diversions/non-statistical/install-middleman-on-windows/), and [Tuts+](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-setup-a-static-website-with-middleman--cms-25275).

When I type `gem install middleman` from `C:/`, it works. I can see `middleman-cli-4.1.10` folder and `middleman-core-4.1.10` folder in: `C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems`

And then I run `middleman init my_site`, it works too. Now, I have (in `my_site` folder): `source`, `.gitignore`, `config.rb`, `config.ru`, `Gemfile`, and `Gemfile.lock`.

But, everytime I run `middleman server` nor `bundle exec middleman server`, it gives me this:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:sass (>= 3.4)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.1.10/bin/middleman:12:in`require':
cannot load such file -- dotenv (LoadError)from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.1.10/bin/middleman:12:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby21/bin/middleman:22:in `load'
from C:/Ruby21/bin/middleman:22:in `<main>'
```

My question is, why does this happen? And how to solve this?

I think that I'm in the wrong folder when I run `middleman init my_site`. If so, then where should I run it? Am I need to run it in a special folder, or I can run it everywhere?

Thank you.

Comment: I think dotenv is a dependency for middleman-cli, but not installed. Try installing it manually using 'gem install dotenv' and then try again.

Comment: @Sam I just run `gem install dotenv`, and then try to run `middleman server`, but still not working, got same warning. I just spend 3 days looking for the solution, I'm using Jekyll now. If you find the solution in the future, please tell me. Thanks, Sam!